# How to install BeautifulSoup 3.2 in Python 3.2 in Windows?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I downloaded the beautifulsoup installation files and `python setup.py install' command fails since it appears to be written in earlier version of python and print method doesn't have braces around the text.

How do I install it in this scenario besides going and fixing all such errors manually?

Comment: can you please include the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup 3.2 is not supported on Python 3. You can use BeautifulSoup 3.1 instead. From the [BeautifulSoup homepage](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

> If you're using Python 3.0, you must use the [3.1 series](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/download/3.1.x/). [Beautiful Soup version 3.1.0.1](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/download/3.1.x/BeautifulSoup-3.1.0.1.tar.gz) was released January 6, 2009. It won't work very well—I consider it a failed experiment—but nothing else works with Python 3.0 at all. [This document describes the problems you'll run into](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/3.1-problems.html), and explains why I abandoned this series.

Note that fixing this goes beyond adding braces to `print` statements: BeautifulSoup 3.2 uses the `sgmllib` library, which has been removed in Python 3.